# Javascript - Why are function calls inside boolean expressions evaluated first?

Tags: javascript, function, boolean-expression

I'll start of with a simplified example of my problem.

```js
function foo(arr) {
  let limit = 1,
      count = 0;

  for (let i=0, len=arr.length; i<len;) {
    if (arr[i] === '0' || arr[i] === '1') {

      let start = i;
      do {
        if (i - start >= limit) {
          count++;
        }
        i++;
      } while (i < len && arr[i] === '0' || arr[i] === '1');
    } else {
      i++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

function bar(arr) {
  let limit = 1,
      count = 0;

  for (let i=0, len=arr.length; i<len;) {
    if (arr[i] === '0' || arr[i].charCodeAt(0) === 49) {

      let start = i;
      do {
        if (i - start >= limit) {
          count++;
        }
        i++;
      } while (i < len && arr[i] === '0' || arr[i].charCodeAt(0) === 49);
    } else {
      i++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

let arr = ['0', '2', '3', '0', '1', '0', '4', '2', '0'];
console.log(bar(arr));
console.log(foo(arr));
```

The above functions return the total count of occurrences of a pattern in an array, starting the count after a certain consecutive limit. They are simplified examples of my actual function, where I want to evaluate an expression like  `arr[i].charCodeAt(0) === 49` only if `i < len`.

**The foo function works as expected, but if I include a function call inside my while condition like in bar, it is evaluated first, and it throws a *TypeError* trying to evaluate an undefined index**.

I could move that expression inside the do-while-loop before *another* `i<len`check. I would like to know why functions are prioritized above "left-to-right" evaluation, and if there is something else I can do to prevent it.

Comment: This is not about function calls. `&&` is prioritized before `||`. You want `i < len && (arr[i] === '0' || arr[i].charCodeAt(0) === 49)`, since currently it’s evaluated as `(i < len && arr[i] === '0') || arr[i].charCodeAt(0) === 49`.

Comment: `while (i < len && arr[i] === '0' || (arr[i] && arr[i].charCodeAt(0) === 49))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it throws a TypeError trying to evaluate an undefined index.

**because `arr[9]` doesn't exists**, just put a console statement to check the same.

**Demo**

```js
function foo(arr) {
  let limit = 1,
      count = 0;

  for (let i=0, len=arr.length; i<len;) {
    if (arr[i] === '0' || arr[i] === '1') {

      let start = i;
      do {
        if (i - start >= limit) {
          count++;
        }
        i++;
      } while (i < len && arr[i] === '0' || arr[i] === '1');
    } else {
      i++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

function bar(arr) {
  let limit = 1,
      count = 0;

  for (let i=0, len=arr.length; i<len;) {
    if (arr[i] === '0' || arr[i].charCodeAt(0) === 49) {

      let start = i;
      do {
        if (i - start >= limit) {
          count++;
        }
        i++;
        console.log(i);
      } while (i < len && arr[i] === '0' || arr[i].charCodeAt(0) === 49);
    } else {
      i++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

let arr = ['0', '2', '3', '0', '1', '0', '4', '2', '0'];
console.log(bar(arr));
console.log(foo(arr));
```

**Explanation**

Your statement is equivalent of writing

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
a < 1 && b < 2 || true; //return true
a < 1 && b < 2 || false; //return false
```

because you have used || in the expression without `()`, it will get evaluated unless first two expressions are `true`.

Use `()` as

```
  } while (i < len && (arr[i] === '0' || arr[i].charCodeAt(0) === 49));
```

**Demo**

```js
function foo(arr) {
  let limit = 1,
      count = 0;

  for (let i=0, len=arr.length; i<len;) {
    if (arr[i] === '0' || arr[i] === '1') {

      let start = i;
      do {
        if (i - start >= limit) {
          count++;
        }
        i++;
      } while (i < len && arr[i] === '0' || arr[i] === '1');
    } else {
      i++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

function bar(arr) {
  let limit = 1,
      count = 0;

  for (let i=0, len=arr.length; i<len;) {
    if (arr[i] === '0' || arr[i].charCodeAt(0) === 49) {

      let start = i;
      do {
        if (i - start >= limit) {
          count++;
        }
        i++;
        console.log(i);
      } while (i < len && (arr[i] === '0' || arr[i].charCodeAt(0) === 49));
    } else {
      i++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

let arr = ['0', '2', '3', '0', '1', '0', '4', '2', '0'];
console.log(bar(arr));
console.log(foo(arr));
```

Comment: I thought I was pretty experienced, but I've always believed that if the first expression was found false followed by && it would exit immediately no matter what followed, and not view the first two, once evaluated, as || to the third. Thank you for teaching me :)

Answer (score 0):

You are running out of your index. But why does bar() raise an exception where foo() does not? Because javascript returns an object of type "undefined" on the out-of-index. But that object does not have a method charCodeAt() and that raises the exception.

```
let arr = ['a', 'b']                    // note there is no arr[2]

console.log(arr[2]);                    // undefined
console.log(arr[2] === undefined);      // true
try
{  console.log(arr[2].charCodeAt(0));
}
catch(e)
{  console.log(e.message);              // Cannot read property 'charCodeAt' of undefined
}
```

Comment: If only I could mark two answers. Why foo didn't raise an exception bothered me, but I see now how both functions went out of bounds. Thank you!